# Surface Pro 3 - unable to select OS to boot. Touchscreen not working in grub. No keyboard

Tags: grub2, grub-efi, surface

Like the title says I'm not able to select what OS to boot from when I don't have my keyboard connected.
The volume keys do not work as a selection device.